# values fetched from database are not going to edit

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing a database app. I succeeded in inserting data but the data is not going to edit . Following is my editing class Please help to solve my problem....

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import com.smartwallet.database.DbAdapterDLicense;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Edit_DLicense extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
private EditText et_cnm,et_idt,et_edt,et_lno,et_add,et_cno,et_ltype;
private Button bt_add;

private Long dlid;  
private Cursor c;
private int mYear,mMonth, mDay;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_IDI = 0;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_IDE = 1;
private String imei_id;
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListenerI;
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListenerE;
private DbAdapterDLicense DBA;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle b) 
{
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.editapp);

    dlid=null;
    Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();

    dlid=(b==null)? null:(Long)b.getSerializable("imei_id");
    if(extras!=null)
    {
        dlid=extras.getLong("imei_id");
    }



    DBA=new DbAdapterDLicense(this);
    DBA.open();

    et_cnm=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_cnm);
    et_idt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_idt);
    et_edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_edt);
    et_lno=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_lno);
    et_add=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_add);
    et_cno=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_cno);
    et_ltype=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_ltype);
    et_idt.setOnClickListener(this);
    et_edt.setOnClickListener(this);

    bt_add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_save);
    bt_add.setOnClickListener(this);        

    mDateSetListenerI = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() 
    {
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) 
            {
                mYear = year;
                mMonth = monthOfYear;
                mDay = dayOfMonth;
                updateDisplay1();
            }
        };

        mDateSetListenerE = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() 
        {
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) 
                {
                    mYear = year;
                    mMonth = monthOfYear;
                    mDay = dayOfMonth;
                    //updateDisplay();
                }
            };

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    //et_cdt.setText(mDay+"/"+(mMonth+1)+"/"+mYear);

    updateDisplay1();
    updateDisplay2();
    updateDL();
}

public void updateDL()
{
    if(dlid!= null)
    {
        c = DBA.fetchDL_imei(dlid);
        startManagingCursor(c);
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            imei_id=c.getString(1);
            et_cnm.setText(c.getString(2));
            et_idt.setText(c.getString(3));
            et_edt.setText(c.getString(4));
            et_lno.setText(c.getString(5));
            et_add.setText(c.getString(6));
            et_cno.setText(c.getString(7));
            et_ltype.setText(c.getString(8));

            bt_add.setText("Save");
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v.equals(bt_add))
    {
        if(dlid==null)
        {
            DBA.updateDL(dlid,Long.parseLong(imei_id),et_cnm.getText().toString(),et_idt.getText().toString(),et_edt.getText().toString(),et_lno.getText().toString(),et_add.getText().toString(),et_cno.getText().toString(),et_ltype.getText().toString(),"true");
            Toast.makeText(Edit_DLicense.this, "Item Updated"+c.getCount(), 2000).show();
            //finish();
        }
        finish();
    }
    else if(v.equals(et_idt))
    {
        showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_IDI);
    }
    else if(v.equals(et_edt))
    {
        showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_IDE);
    }
}

private void updateDisplay1() 
{
    et_idt.setText(""+mDay+"/"+(mMonth+1)+"/"+mYear);   
}
private void updateDisplay2() 
{
    et_edt.setText(""+mDay+"/"+(mMonth+1)+"/"+mYear);   
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
{
    if(id==DATE_DIALOG_IDI)
    {
        return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                mDateSetListenerI,
                mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    }
    else if(id==DATE_DIALOG_IDE)
    {
        return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                mDateSetListenerE,
                mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DBA.close();
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

and this is my adapter class

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class DbAdapterDLicense 
{

public static final String DLID = "dlid";
public static final String IMEI_ID="imei_id";
public static final String U_NAME="c_nm";
public static final String I_DATE="i_date";
public static final String E_DATE = "e_date";
public static final String L_NO = "l_no";
public static final String CL_NO="cl_no";
public static final String C_ADDR="c_addr";
public static final String L_TYPE="l_type";
public static final String EXE_FLAG="exe_flg";
private static final String T_DLICENSE = "DrivingLicense";

private Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private DbHelper dbHelper;

public DbAdapterDLicense(Context context) 
{
    this.context = context;
}

public DbAdapterDLicense open() throws SQLException 
{
    dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() 
{
    dbHelper.close();
}

//For Appointment Table
public long insertDL(long imei_id,String c_nm,String i_date, String e_date,String    l_no,String cl_no,String c_addr,String l_type,String exe_flg) 
{
    ContentValues values = createContentValues_dl(imei_id,c_nm,i_date, e_date, l_no,cl_no,c_addr,l_type,exe_flg);
    return db.insert(T_DLICENSE, null, values);
}

public boolean updateDL(long rowId, long imei_id,String c_nm,String i_date, String e_date,String l_no,String cl_no,String c_addr,String l_type,String exe_flg) 
{
    ContentValues values = createContentValues_dl(imei_id,c_nm,i_date, e_date, l_no,cl_no,c_addr,l_type,exe_flg);
    return db.update(T_DLICENSE, values, DLID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

public boolean updateDL_imei(long rowId, long imei_id,String c_nm,String i_date, String e_date,String l_no,String cl_no,String c_addr,String l_type,String exe_flg) 
{
    ContentValues values = createContentValues_dl(imei_id,c_nm,i_date, e_date, l_no,cl_no,c_addr,l_type,exe_flg);
    return db.update(T_DLICENSE, values, IMEI_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

public boolean deleteDL(long rowId) 
{
    return db.delete(T_DLICENSE, IMEI_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

public Cursor fetchAllDL() 
{
    return db.query(T_DLICENSE, new String[] { DLID, IMEI_ID,U_NAME,I_DATE,E_DATE,L_NO,CL_NO,C_ADDR,L_TYPE,EXE_FLAG}, null, null, null, null, null);
}

public Cursor fetchDL(long rowId) throws SQLException 
{
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(true,T_DLICENSE, new String[] {DLID, IMEI_ID,U_NAME,I_DATE,E_DATE,L_NO,CL_NO,C_ADDR,L_TYPE,EXE_FLAG}, DLID + "="
            + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null)
    {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

public Cursor fetchDL_imei(long rowId) throws SQLException 
{
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(true,T_DLICENSE, new String[] {DLID, IMEI_ID,U_NAME,I_DATE,E_DATE,L_NO,CL_NO,C_ADDR,L_TYPE,EXE_FLAG}, IMEI_ID + "="
            + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null)
    {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

private ContentValues createContentValues_dl(long imei_id,String c_nm,String i_date, String e_date,String l_no,String cl_no,String c_addr,String l_type,String exe_flg)
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(IMEI_ID, imei_id);
    values.put(U_NAME, c_nm);
    values.put(I_DATE, i_date);
    values.put(E_DATE, e_date);
    values.put(L_NO, l_no);
    values.put(CL_NO, cl_no);
    values.put(C_ADDR, c_addr);
    values.put(L_TYPE, l_type);
    values.put(EXE_FLAG, exe_flg);
    return values;
}
}
```

is there any issue of flag?? in editing. I also used flag here in adding values class and editing values classes. Where to set true and where to set false? Is that issues? 
I tried very much but th values are not editing .....Please suggest solution(s).

Answer (score 0):

Your code for the update seems to be wrong.  The arguments for the db.update should be:
update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)

You seem to be trying to pass the whole thing in the whereClause instead of putting the value you are using in the whereArgs.

I believe it should be:
db.update(T_DLICENSE, values, DLID + "= ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(rowid) });

Comment: Ohh!! thanks but it does not solving my problem..... any more solution(s).. Please

Comment: I presume you have stepped through your code to check that dlid isn't null when you try to run the update?  Are you getting an error? You could also wrap your update in a transaction e.g. db.beginTransaction(); try{ //run edit then db.setTransactionSuccessful();} catch(Exception){//show error} finally{db.endTransaction();}

Comment: nope its not giving any error or exception but also not updating the edited values I removed dlid==null statement but still its not updating values.

Comment: is there any issue of flag?? in editing. I used flag here in adding values class and editing values classes. Where to set true and where to set false? Is that issues?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last comment but I have read through your code again and think I see a problem (but forgive me if I have missed something).  It looks like the dlid is last assigned in your oncreate as 'dlid=extras.getLong("imei_id");' but you have a seperate column for imei_id.  Assuming dlid is the primary key and effectively a row count should you not be using this value for your update condition instead of the imei_id or are they the same thing in your table? Or should your update query be 'db.update(T_DLICENSE, values, "imei_id = ?",new String[] { String.valueOf(rowid) });'?